# Docker containers install new packages in requirements.txt on start

Tags: python, docker

I want my docker containers to install packages added to `requirements.txt` on startup - if there were any changes.

Given a Dockerfile which looks as follows

```
FROM python 

WORKDIR /opt/code

COPY ./requirements.txt /opt/code/requirements.txt

...

RUN pip --no-cache-dir install --upgrade -r requirements.txt

...
```

And assuming this `requirements.txt` file is volume mapped so it's visible from outside the container I want to be able to manage packages by changing `requirements.txt` and then calling `docker restart my_container`.
Notice, I don't want old packages to be upgraded, only new ones installed.

As a bonus, it would be great if I could write to a log file if new packages were installed only the name of the newly installed ones (avoiding the "already installed" messages)

Comment: This would usually be part of building a Docker image from a Dockerfile with `docker build`.

Comment: obviously, but after its up, if I want to install new libraries i must `docker exec my_container pip install django` but I don't want to do that, I want to write `django` into `requirements.txt` and run `docker restart my_container`

Comment: You should create a new image if you have new requirements. The Dockerfile should always generate an image that can spawn a new container with your most recent code instantly. When you want to run a new code, you build a new image with all dependencies, stop the old container and run a new one from the new image.

Comment: Why not update your entrypoint/cmd to run a pip install before launching your app?

Comment: @BMitch the entry points is used for the process that will keep alive, so the container won't shut itself down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make an entrypoint script that performs this before running your app. I'd likely deploy this using a compose file rather than directly in the image so that you don't have a dynamically updating container in production.

Here's an example entrypoint script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# if a command is not provided, set a default command
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  set -- python app.py
fi
# update to new requirements on each container start
pip --no-cache-dir install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
# use exec to replace pid 1 with the command (e.g. python app.py)
exec "$@"
```

The Dockerfile would have this added, but I wouldn't change the current command:

```
COPY entrypoint-dev.sh /
```

Then in your development compose file, you can use that entrypoint:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: app:dev
    entrypoint:
    - /entrypoint-dev.sh
    volumes:
    - .:/opt/code
```